# Android - Issue in posting on facebook wall using facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I've used facebook sdk to post on facebook wall. I've create app id in developer facebook and i used following code to post on facebook wall.

```
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);  
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "publish_actions" };
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", message);
parameters.putString("description", "topic share");

try {
    facebook.request("me");
    String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
    Log.d(TAG, "got response: " + response);       
} catch (Exception e) {       
}
```

The above code is working only for one facebook account in which the appid contains. If you try to login through some other facebook accounts. its showing following error.

{"error":{"message":"(#200) **The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Kamal

Comment: If your app is in debug mode, you can use it only with your own account or create test developer accounts. Go to your app info on Facebook, open Roles tab in left menu and choose "Test Users" tab. There you can add users.

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be done before you can use `publish_actions` for every user:

- Set your App to public in the "Settings & Review" tab of your App settings
- Go through the review process with `publish_actions`

The review process is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Without review, `publish_actions` will only work for users with a role in your App.

Also, make sure you know about the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) before using `publish_actions` > the message must be 100% user generated.

Comment: did you add any platform?

Comment: well, you MUST add a platform...in your case, android

Comment: As per your comment i've submitted for review in developer facebook but they are telling that Your app can't auto-populate the message field with any content. Review Comments - People must enter all content in the user message field. Your app can't auto-populate the message field with any content, including links and hashtags, even if you allow users to edit the content before sharing. Please remove any pre-filled text from your shared content before resubmitting for review.

Comment: yes, that´s correct. you are not allowed to use any message, it must be user generated.